# Cordova TypeScript - Visual Studio - Android Build failed - No error

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have successfully tested a Cordova JavaScript app on both Android and Windows 8.1. I thought: Let's use TypeScript, so I deleted the previous project and created a new TypeScript project.
When I do rebuild all / debug, I get a build failed when targeting Android. When targeting Windows everything is fine.

No errors in the build log do. This is the output:

```
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins:
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What should I do to investigate this further?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! I deleted the folder /platforms/Android, and then it created the folder again.